# Get center screen position of view in landscape orientation

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, orientation, landscape

At the moment I have an `UIImageView` inside a window. When the scene loads I save its position with:

```
imageView.center
```

The user can drag it around. On some occasions the item gets animated back to its original position which has been saved. This all works fine, when I hold the IPad vertically.

When I hold it horizontally though I cant move it back to that position, because in landscape mode I cant use the position which was saved in vertical orientation mode. this is because in Interface Builder I set the item to get auto sized relative to the borders (meaning if the item was in the center, then rotating the IPad it still stays in center)

So my question is: How can I get the correct original position the item would have in landscape orientation?

I tried to calculate the position by hand like this:

```
- (CGPoint)getHorizontalCoordinatesForPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    CGSize size = [[UIScreen mainScreen]applicationFrame].size;
    CGFloat relativeX = (point.x / (size.width));
    CGFloat relativeY = point.y / (size.height);
    CGFloat horizontalScreenX = relativeX * (size.height);
    CGFloat horizontalScreenY = relativeY * (size.width);
    return CGPointMake(horizontalScreenX, horizontalScreenY);
}
```

but this position is a bit off. I think it is because I dont take into account the size of the navigation bar. Is there some converting function in ios which already does what I want?

Answer (score 1):

Don't.

Rather, instead of saving [imageView center] when the scene loads, save it at key points:

-touchesBegan:withEvent: (or, if you are using gesture recognizers, in the gesture recognizer callback).

-didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:

The minor complication is what happens if a user, say, is working in landscape, quits the app, rotates the portrait, and relaunches the app.  In this case I would start the app in landscape and let the autorotation to portrait kick in and correct your center point.

Comment: But isnt there the same problem, when the user touches in portrait mode, and you save the location then you also only get the portrait mode location. When you then drag the imageview, then rotate to landscape, then the item should animate back it chooses the wrong position. Starting the app in landsape mode doesnt help either, because you only get the landsape position.

Comment: Fixed this for now, because I also needed another UIView at the original Location of the icon. This UIView is fixed so I just reset the dragable icon to the position of this view. Works with landscape as well as portrait mode. Its some kind of hack but I do need to show this view anyway.